# How to write the same data over and over on a file?

Tags: python, file

I want to make a script that will allow me to write N times the same paragraph of data but I have no idea how to do it, can you help me?

i tried this :

```
fin = open("C:\\ProgramData\\OutilTestObjets3D\\MaquetteCB-2019\\DataSet\\1212.osg", "rt")
fout = open("C:\\ProgramData\\OutilTestObjets3D\\MaquetteCB-2019\\DataSet\\testreecrtiure.osg", "wt")

for line in fin:
             fout.write(line.write("...."))
```

but i dont know if i have to use a loop or something like this

Comment: What qualifies as a paragraph in your infile? Can you show an excerpt of the file?

Comment: this is something like that : Group {
  DataVariance DYNAMIC
  nodeMask 0xffffffff
  cullingActive TRUE
  num_children 3
  PositionAttitudeTransform {
    DataVariance DYNAMIC
    nodeMask 0xffffffff
    cullingActive TRUE
@ilmiacs

Comment: This is not yet very helpful. Your loop is going to fetch the data from the file line by line. The question is, how many lines does your paragraph have that you want to repeat N lines. You somehow need to detect what qualifies as a paragraph. From your question and comment this is not yet clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation which writes the input file 42 times.

```
with open('output', 'w') as fout:
    for x in range(42):
        with open('input', 'r') as fin:
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line)
```

Instead of repeatedly closing and reopening the input file, you can rewind it with `seek()` if you wish; but I prefer this approach, which also takes care of automatically closing both files at the end, which you forgot to do in your code.

(You should probably avoid hard-coding absolute paths in your code.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fin = open("C:\\ProgramData\\OutilTestObjets3D\\MaquetteCB-2019\\DataSet\\1212.osg", "r")
fout = open("C:\\ProgramData\\OutilTestObjets3D\\MaquetteCB-2019\\DataSet\\testreecrtiure.osg", "w")


for line in fin:
    fout.write(line)

fin.seek(0,0)

for line in fin:
    fout.write(line)
```

Once you finish "read and write", the pointer of "fin" should be moved to the beginning.

So you need to add this line：`fin.seek(0,0)` before you start another "read and write".

Here is the code of write N times

```
fin = open("C:\\ProgramData\\OutilTestObjets3D\\MaquetteCB-2019\\DataSet\\1212.osg", "r")
fout = open("C:\\ProgramData\\OutilTestObjets3D\\MaquetteCB-2019\\DataSet\\testreecrtiure.osg", "w")

N=5  # For example, repeat 5 times
for count in range(0,N):
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line)
    fin.seek(0,0)
```